# How can I process incoming emails using PHP

Tags: php, email

I'm fairly new at using PhP, and I'm trying to write a script that will:

1. Connect to a mail server
2. Retrieve new emails
3. For each new email, extract as variables the sender's email address, the subject, and the message in plain text.
4. Mark the message as read once processed

The script would use these variables to interact with my database, and would be triggered by a CronJob every minute to check for new mails.

I've looked around a found a handful of library that apparently allow to interact with emails (IMAP, Zend Mail...). Before going any further, I have a few questions:

- Do I need to install a library (I've never used one before) or do PhP have functions that would allow me to do what I want without having to install anything?
- If PhP itself can do it, where can I find a tutorial helping me with that?
- If I need a library, which one would recommand using and where can I find a tutorial to help me with it?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Arthur

Comment: Well, to use `imap` you have to use the `imap` extension, but it might already be installed. To use any downloadable library (without installation - just PHP), you still need the `sockets` extension. The manual pages for PHP imap are pretty good.

Comment: Thanks buddy, figured it out thanks to you ;)

Comment: You're welcome - glad you figured it out. It'd be awesome if you could post an answer yourself with your discoveries so anyone else googling what you google'd will find your answer and solve their own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those with the same issue:
http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap

For French-speaking people (the code is understandable by non-French speakers):
http://nicolas-vieux.developpez.com/tutoriels/php/fonctions-imap/